# Linux Executable fails to run with error “/usr/bin/strace: exec: No such file or directory” on running strace

Tags: strace, elf

I need to analyse linux binary executable file using strace for capturing the system calls. On running the command:

`/usr/bin/strace ./005f32fffe1da3bc100e7dcd8b2f8f2c`

I got this error:

```
execve("./005f32fffe1da3bc100e7dcd8b2f8f2c", ["./005f32fffe1da3bc100e7dcd8b2f8f"...], 0x7fffd9d0a120 /* 53 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) fstat(2, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0 write(2, "/usr/bin/strace: exec: No such f"..., 49/usr/bin/strace: exec: No such file or directory ) = 49 getpid() = 3699 exit_group(1) = ? +++ exited with 1 +++
```

My file type is 32 bit ELF binary.

```
file 005f32fffe1da3bc100e7dcd8b2f8f2c 
005f32fffe1da3bc100e7dcd8b2f8f2c: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-, stripped
```

Comment: That binary is dynamically linked. Are all the dynamically linked libs available? `ldd` will display that information

Comment: Either your binary or `file(1)` is broken: I don't think there's any `/lib/ld-` interpreter (dynamic linker). Also add the output of `readelf -a that_binary | grep interpreter`, and details on how you created it or where you obtained it from.

Comment: The output of `ldd 005f32fffe1da3bc100e7dcd8b2f8f2c` is `linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7f49000)  libumsg.so => not found
 libubox.so => not found
 libucrypto.so => not found
 libuc++.so => not found
 libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7f10000)
 libc.so.0 => not found
 libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf7d37000)
 /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0 => /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7f4b000)`

Comment: output of `readelf -a 005f32fffe1da3bc100e7dcd8b2f8f2c | grep interpreter`  is `[Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0]`

Comment: I am doing research on iot botnet and I got these files from a github repository for my research.

Comment: @steeldriver what system and file version is that? I cannot reproduce it on either rhel8 or debian10. To the OP: add that info into the Q, not in comments. And the next step is to check if `/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0` really exists ;-) (the output of `ldd` is irrelevant for this, since `ldd` will use a "safe" interpreter instead of that from the binary's header)

Comment: Are you running a 64bit system? If so, have you got any of the 32bit libraries installed at all?

Comment: @roaima yes my system in Ubuntu 64 bit. I have libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32z1 installed.

Comment: @all - I am unable to run this file on my machine without strace. Does that mean that this file is not meant to work on my architecture? Is there any workaround to make these files work ?